# How do I prevent traffic on my site from a source other than Cloudflare?

Tags: firewalls, ddos, cloudflare

I use *Google Cloud Platform* to serve the site I manage.

I have one *load balancer* there, which controls the movement to several *virtual machines*.

When I came across the problem of ***DDOS*** attacks on this site, I started using *Google Armor* to block the intruders' IP addresses, but over time, when the problem escalated, my team decided to use the ***Cloudflare*** service and now all domain traffic from the Internet to service is lead by Cloudflare as a middleman.

However, further *DDOS* incidents show that the attack is carried out in two ways: using the domain (or domain IP referring to *Cloudflare*), but also directly on the *load balancer's* *IP* from *Google Claud*.

The attackers could have known this load *balancer's IP*, before joining *Cloudflare*, because that *IP* has not changed.

I would like all traffic to be directed by *Cloudflare* and, if possible, that nobody from the outside knows the *load balancer's*  *IP* or *virtual servers* located in the *Google Cloud*.

**I have two questions:**

1. **If I change the *load balancer's IP* address now, can someone from the outside (attacker) get to this *IP* in some way?**
2. I could use *Google Armor* (or another *firewall*) to allow *Google Claud* to accept traffic only from *Cloudflare*, but **is there such a permanent (immutable) list of *IP* addresses that are only used by *Cloudflare* to communicate with my site (or all sites) to which I could restrict traffic?**

Maybe someone else has some other ideas as to the situation and he would like to share them. I am happy to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you change the public IP address of your site, configure the DNS to point to Cloudflare and forward your request from there, the attacker will always go through the Cloudflare and won't hit your server directly.

Cloudflare publishes its public IP list that you can restrict on your perimeter. The list is available at https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

Comment: This will help, but won't necessarily stop determined attacks. The main booter/stresser sites now advertise the fact that they can take down cloudflare sites. They are able to bypass cloudflare captchas, they use real browsers, and they are now starting to use cloudflare's WARP VPN (so only allowing cloudflare ips to your real server will not stop the attacks if they know your real server ip).

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at [Argo Tunnel](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/argo-tunnel/), a feature of CloudFlare.

By letting their daemon run on your server, it will ensure that only Cloudflare servers can contact yours.